# Alert and confirm in NativeScript web view

Tags: nativescript

We've recently discovered that inside a web view on Android

- confirm does not work- it causes execution to stop.
- alert does not work- it does nothing.

However, both confirm and alert work as expected in IOs. Our web view uses code that is shared with our website. What is the simplest way to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    webView.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function (args: webViewModule.LoadEventData)
    {
        //console.log( "web-view.url=" + args.url );

        if ( platformModule.isAndroid )
        {
            class MyWebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient
            {
                constructor()
                {
                    super();
                    return global.__native(this);
                }

                init()
                {
                    return global.__native(this);
                }

                onJsAlert( webview: android.webkit.WebView, url: string, msg: string, result: android.webkit.JsResult ) : boolean
                {
                    // my function - but NS has one also
                    utils.errorDialog( msg, "MESSAGE" );
                    
                    result.confirm();
                    
                    return true;
                }
            }
                        
            (<webViewModule.WebView>args.object).android.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );

            (<webViewModule.WebView>args.object).android.setWebChromeClient( new MyWebChromeClient() );
        }
```

If you don't want the sub-class

`(<webViewModule.WebView>args.object).android.setWebChromeClient( new android.webkit.WebChromeClient() );`